# Route model binding get object undefined when use laravel jwt

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Im using laravel 6 with tymon/jwt-auth 1.0 package, Im only try to create CRUD application. When I try to send PUT method to update database, unfortunately, route model binding can not find object with id I gave in url. I've checked some cases:

- Route list exist put method and model binding variable is matched
- Change middleware with api, it worked
- GET, POST working fine
- Model use soft delete but this record doesn't deleted

I check response with put method I get info with default of object model:

```
{
    parent_task: null,
    status: {id: "-999", slug: "notfound", name: "Not Found", color: "black", actived: false}
}
```

Here are some steps I've done:

**1. Register middleware in Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    'auth.jwt'  =>  \Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class, // JWT middleware
];
```

**2. Load route in ModuleServiceProvider.php**

```
$config = config('modules');
foreach ($config as $module) {
    $namespace = "App\Modules\\".$module."\Controllers";
    $routePath = app_path("Modules/$module/Routes/apx.php");
    if ( File::exists($routePath) ) {
        Route::prefix('apx')->middleware(['auth.jwt', 'cors'])->namespace($namespace)->group($routePath);
    }
}
```

**3. Register route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'com'], function() {
    Route::get('tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@getDetail');
    Route::put('tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@putSave')->name('A_1');
    Route::post('tasks', 'TaskController@postSave')->name('A_2');
});
```

**4. Write a put method**

```
// update
public function putSave(SaveRequest $request, Task $task)
{
    $task->update($request->all());
    return $task;
}
```

I can not see what wrong in here, please help me.